# Qt wont run the app for Android

Tags: qt, qtkit, android-virtual-device

I have been working with Qt Desktop for a year now, and I needed to set up the environment for Android. I have followed carefully the steps in Qt documentations, downloaded Android SDK, NDK, Ant and JDK 7. I included all the paths and created a kit for Android. I installed the latest Android APIs and System Images from SDK and also created a AVD Nexus running Android 5.1.

I created a project (when i create a Widget project, in the supported platforms at the right, Android is not shown, as in tutorial I have seen) and build and run it on Desktop - eveything Ok. When I try to run it on Android, a pop up shows, wanting the path of the executable, saying it can not find it. I don't know what to include here, cause in all the tutorials I have seen the AVD should start automatically (it is on, in the moment I try to run from Qt).

I don't what other settings to check, been seven hours now, trying to figure out the problem. I think the problem is in the Kit or in the Debugger, or in the Qt Version that can not detect the Android Kits or AVDs. Or it is just a silly thing that just need a path for the executable when running. These are all my system setting, please let me know if you need other info:

```
Qt Creator 3.3.2 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.4.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

Android Kit:
Name: Android
File System Name: empty
Device Type: Android Device
Device: Run on Android(default for Android)
Sysroot: empty
Compiler: MinGw 4.9.1 32bit
Environment: No Changes to apply
Debugger: Android Debugger (I also tried to leave this Auto Detect, it was the same)
Android GDB server: Auto-Detect (I also tried including: C:\Qt_for_Android\android-ndk-r10e\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver, it was the same)
Qt Version: Qt 5.4.1 MinGW 32bit
Qt mkspec: empty
```

Qt Versions:
Auto-Detected: QtQt %{Qt:Version} MinGW 32bit
no Manual

Compilers:
MinGW 4.9.1 32 bit
and several others for Android GCC (arm-4.8, mips, x86), but when I try to include them into the Android Kit, the Kit is not Available, I can choose only MinGW, which seems the most probable problem to me.

Debuggers:

```
Auto-Detect:
GNU gdb 7.8 for MinGW
CDB at ...
Manual"
Android with path : C:\Qt_for_Android\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe
```

I really don't know what the problem is, and I need to start soon.

Comment: Are you doing this on windows? And is it for arm or mips processor etc?

Comment: I think the problem is downloading the correct compiler for your processor architecture type. There's Android GCC (arm), Android GCC (mips), Android GCC (x86) etc.

Comment: I am on Windows 8.1. I guess I have all of them downloaded. But how come, it pops up the windows saying it can find the executable? I haven't seen it anywhere.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should check all the parameters when creating the AVD? or in the kits, compilers on qt? I have seen too many examples, tutorials, etc, nothing seems to help. If you could provide me with any link or similiar problem would be great!

Comment: https://bytedebugger.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/tutorial-how-to-use-qt-creator-for-mobile-development-android/